# Find two basis so that the application matrix is the identity

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got the matrix:
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&1&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}

That is an application matrix between canonical basis. I need to find two basis B1 on the entry space and B2 on the exit space so that the application matrix Mb1b2(f)=I.

I can't find out how to do this.

Comment: Can you diagonalize it, maybe?

Comment: How? With the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @mathreadler That won’t work. The only diagonalizable matrix that’s similar to the identity is the identity itself. This exam question isn’t about eigensystems but rather about understanding the meaning of coordinates and what the columns of a transformation matrix represent.

Comment: Seems at least someone is awake, John.

Answer (score 0):

If $B_1=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ are the vectors of the standard basis, then $B_2=\{Ae_1,Ae_2,Ae_3\}$ is a basis, because the matrix has rank $3$.

The matrix with respect to these two bases is the identity.

If you don't want $B_1$ to be the standard basis (but the problem as stated doesn't require it), just take your favorite nonstandard basis $B_1=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and define $B_2=\{Av_1,Av_2,Av_3\}$.

Comment: But B1 cant be the canonical, its another basis.

Comment: @JosuBlanco No problem, see the addition.

Comment: I've thought of that but it seemed too easy for an exam question. Thanks!